# Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException Parse error on line 1:

Tags: php, composer-php

I was doing composer update

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/myproject$ composer update
```

and all of a sudden this came in red:

```
[Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]
Invalid repository data in /home/vagrant/code/myproject/vendor/composer/installed.json, packages could not be loaded: [Seld\JsonLint\
ParsingException] "/home/vagrant/code/myproject/vendor/composer/installed.json" does not contain valid JSON
Parse error on line 1:

^
Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

What should I do?

Comment: `composer install` command gives the same message.

Comment: Delete `vendor` directory and then try again.

Comment: Actually only `composer install` worked, let me try `composer update`

Comment: It worked now, I see that last time on `composer update` the process did not come to the point where it should say `Writing lock file`. Apparently that was a reason for an error.

Answer (score 4):

The best option available is for you to delete your vendor directory and run

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 4):

As rob006 suggested I deleted vendor directory and then tried again.

first `composer install` worked.

Then `composer update` worked.

I see that last time on `composer update` the process did not come to the point where it should say `Writing lock file`.

Apparently that was a reason for an error.

Answer (score 2):

As the main error is in installed.json file so copy the file and rename it to installed_old.json

```
 project_name/vendor/composer/installed.json to installed_old.json
```

Now do

```
composer update
```

this will resolve the issue